# Data size for ascii representation of 32bit floats

Tags: ascii, 32-bit, data-representation

If the largest 32 bit number I can express is 0xFFFFFFFF, then in ascii representation, is this 64 bits in size (in hex)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming you use one octet per ascii character, as is conventional. However you might also need a terminating nul, and maybe the "0x" prefix. Also you can use a 7 bit representation for ascii, it's still an ascii encoding (though hard to work with on 8-bit based platforms).